# No bluetooth after kernel update, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa X80)

Tags: 20.04, kernel, bluetooth

Bluetooth has disappeared after kernel update today, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa X80). Laptop Dell Inpiron 15 3000.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by X80, but please be precise with details.  If you're using Ubuntu 20.04.2 you're well behind on upgrades & security fixes; as an updated system will report as 20.04.3 ([this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/) shows ISO release date but installed systems updated to 20.04.3 before 26 August-2021); and beyond that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has multiple kernels, 5.4 is the GA kernel. 5.11 the HWE *stable*, 5.13 the HWE *edge* with more OEM kernels... so please check your details; apply all updates & correct any details & be specific.

Comment: uname -a returns: 5.11.0-46-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 06:51:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
 I have completed update of 20.04.2 system, and changed kernel to 5.11. I have no more upgrades of the LTS system available. Concerning 21.04, I don't want to install it.

Comment: How does 21.04 relate?  I didn't mention it and I perfectly understand not wanting to use it as it's in it's last days of support (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html).  You're likely using 20.04.3 though not 20.04.2 as the HWE kernel at 20.04.2 was 5.8; 5.11 appeared at 20.04.3 so I'd check as you'll likely find you're using 20.04.3 UNLESS you have other issues as your details don't *align* or *match up* (`lsb_release -a` will show release details). I still don't know what you mean by X80; are you using something based on Ubuntu 20.04.2 and not Ubuntu?

Comment: I fully upgraded 20.04.2, then I have installed the package linux-generic-hwe-20.04. And system doesn't see bluetooth adapter.

Comment: Your release is 20.04 with .2 being the upgrade level; ie. that will change to .3, .4, .4 etc as you apply upgrades. If it's still reporting your system as 20.04.2 then something is wrong unless you're not using Ubuntu at all (*and you're off-topic here if that's the case as we don't know your system*).  Some commands may show your installation level (ie. will always say 20.04.2 if that's what you installed), but your lack of correct results are where I'd concentrate efforts. Additional details should be added to your question (inc. commands you used to get details as that could be your issue)

Comment: In window "System Information" is written "Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa X80)". uname -a returns: 5.11.0-46-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 06:51:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I have found that bios settings of bluetooth are none. I've not found how to change it. Previously, bluetooth functions normally.

Comment: I have updated to 20.04.3. System information shows Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I have RTL8821CE WiFi and Bluetooth adapter. WiFi works, Bluetooth not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133234/discussion-between-mahler-and-guiverc).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the Bluetooth works on 22.04 Jammy with new linux-firmware package.

```
linux-firmware:
  Installed: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.11
```

Comment: Not an answer. Needs details what new firmware?

Comment: The linux-firmware package from the Jammy repository is meant in the answer. One simply needs to upgrade the system.

Comment: That may have been true the day you wrote it but later like now an actual version number is needed for a good answer.

Comment: I made edit the answer. It is 3.11 version of linux-firmware.